# Awful frame rates under all browsers (Pixi JS Rendering)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, frame-rate, pixi.js

I'm drawing an isometric grid with mouse-over hit area detection over each tile. It works but the frame rates are awful. Any idea what is bringing the frame-rates down so much? Surely, webGL is capable of attaining better FPS than this?

There are no moving sprites (only diamond-shapes PIXI.Graphics) drawn to the screen.

http://178.79.155.146/pc

Cheers,
Jordan

Comment: I animate with PIXI.Graphics objects all the time, and have never had problems like you describe. I'd suggest you post some code.

Answer (score -3):

As a follow-up. With primitives we have to draw them to the stencil buffer each frame, then render that to the render buffer. With a sprite it is a single draw call to show the texture. If you have many sprites with the same texture we can batch them all together in a single draw call (we can't do that with Graphics).

Summary: For performance, use sprites (not WebGL primitive graphics!).

Comment: WebGL graphics are as efficient as you make them. [Here's an isometric game in WebGL running just fine](http://danielmagliola.com/demos/isoengine/). [Here's another](http://mitallast.github.io/diablo-js/). There's plenty more

Comment: That's not the case with the PIXI library. It IS an efficiency problem with openGL to do with primitives.

Comment: Sprites are drawn with primitives. Your perf issue has nothing to do with WebGL or OpenGL